# What to use - modulus or bitwise AND operator when creating an implementation of a Hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, indexing, hashmap, modulo, bitwise-and

I have a university assignment in which we are to create our own HashMap implementation. In the assignment, when calculating the index of an entry to be placed in the array, it says to use the modulus operator:

```
int index = key.hashCode() % array.length;
```

But from everything I have gathered in my own research, the proper way to do it is using a bitwise AND operator:

```
int index = key.hashCode() & (array.length - 1);
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages with these approaches? Does it matter or is one preferred? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator is correct for all sizes of a hash map.  It will, as evenly as possible, distribute hash codes across all buckets.

But Java's `HashMap` uses a bit-and operation to get the bucket number.  When the number of buckets is a power of 2, then `& (array.length - 1)` is equivalent to `% array.length`, but a simple bitwise operation is faster than modulus, which requires a division operation.

While the modulus operator will work for any number of buckets, if you have the number of buckets as power of 2, then use the equivalent bit-and operation for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Modulus operator can produce duplicates so I guess your assignment specification is wrong since modulus operator can only output numbers **from 0 to array.length-1**

Example lets say length is 3. HashCodes are big and calculated depending on the key itself so they can be anything. Modulus with 3 only can produce numbers {0,1,2} so chances of duplication is pretty high

1111 mod 3 -> is 1

2221 mod 3 -> is also 1

so we have duplicate indexes which breaks the purpose of having indexes because they are no longer unique.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about distribution, validation and optimisation: the modulo of a negative `int` (some `hashCode()`) may return **a negative value**.

The bitwise and here is an optimisation removing the unwanted bits (the negative bit sign), thus avoiding the extra negative check: if I take the example from first answer, here is the result with some values using modulo and using bitwise and.

```
System.out.printf("1111 %% 3 = %d%n", 1111 % 3); // 1111 % 3 = 1
System.out.printf("2221 %% 3 = %d%n", 2221 % 3); // 2221 % 3 = 1
System.out.printf("3331 %% 3 = %d%n", 3331 % 3); // 3331 % 3 = 1
System.out.printf("-1 %% 3 = %d%n", -1 % 3); // -1 % 3 = -1

System.out.printf("1111 & 2 = %d%n", 1111 & 2); // 1111 & 2 = 2
System.out.printf("2221 & 2 = %d%n", 2221 & 2); // 2221 & 2 = 0
System.out.printf("3331 & 2 = %d%n", 3331 & 2); // 3331 & 2 = 2
System.out.printf("-1 & 2 = %d%n", -1 & 2);     // -1 & 2 = 2
```

You can see the result here: https://onlinegdb.com/ffVoyifb0

This also means the distribution is different - which may be another reason of why it is used in `HashMap`.

Note that for that to work, the `array.length` should be probably be multiple of 2:

```
// good = only 2^4 = 16 possible values
array.length = 16 = 0b0001_0000
array.length - 1 = 15 = 0b0000_1111

// bad = only two possible values
array.length = 17 = 0b0001_0001
array.length - 1 = 16 = 0b0001_0000
```

In the JDK 7, the `HashMap` constructor try to find a capacity multiple of 2: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L198

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise AND operator will give the results in a range of the second operator and give good randomness over that range, for example:

9 & 3 will give 1
9 % 3 will give 0

6 & 3 will give 2
6 % 3 will again give 0

12 & 3 will give 0
12 % 3 will again give 0

Also, a bitwise operation is faster when compared to a modulus as a modulus operation goes through multiple steps during processing.
That is why it's good to use bitwise AND over modulo operation to spread out the results for calculating indexes in Map implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would only use a bit-mask operation if you knew for certain the hash was strongly decorrelated from the input data and all bits of the hash were properly scrambled.

The use of remainder, typically by a prime number, offers some improvement in smoothing out the distribution and minimising collisions if you have either a bad hash function or an identity hash function.  But it is slower.

You can also use other transforms if you apply a bit of number theory.  Depending on the scenario.